# Background script doesn't persist for the lifetime of the extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

From this source (https://medium.com/@vanessajimenez_85032/chrome-extensions-content-scripts-vs-background-scripts-7bbd01f9dbe6):

"A persistent background page exists during the lifetime of the extension and only one instance of it actively running in the background of the Chrome browser waiting for the user to interact with the extension"

I have a hunch that I misunderstood what this means; I'm currently coding an extension that uses a timer in my background.js, but the timer doesn't persist across different (INDEPENDENT) chrome windows. If I have a timer going on one window and open another, my extension on both windows will have the same timer progress - however if I close all chrome windows and open a new one, my timer will restart at 00:00. I want my timer to persist across any and all Chrome windows: do background scripts not actually work like this?

Here's my code in case I made a programming mistake:

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Drill Sergeant",
  "description": "Tracks time spent on 'watchlist' websites",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background": {"scripts": ["background.js"]},
  "web_accessible_resources": ["background.js"],
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "webNavigation", "notifications", "tabs"]
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab)
{
       var timer = setInterval(countDown, 1000);
});

var timeCount =
{
  duration:timeOut,
  text: "OK"
}
function countDown()
{
    timeCount.duration--;
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(timeCount);
}
```

popup.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        var min, sec;
        var minStr, secStr;
        min = Math.floor(request.duration/60);
        sec = request.duration % 60;

        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = minStr + ":" + secStr;

);
```

Comment: What is an "INDEPENDENT" window? If it's a different user profile, then there's a copy of your extension, which is not related to the one from another user profile. Also, exposing background.js in web_accessible_resources isn't right, although usually harmless.

Comment: Actually, I think I see what you want. You need to add `"background"` in manifest's `"permissions"` and enable "Continue running background apps when Chrome is closed" in the browser settings.